# Using condition on Cursor, when it's Emty( NOT FOUND) in DB2

Tags: cursor, db2

I want to make a condition on Cursor like in Oracle (IF cur%NOTFOUND THEN ..).
I tried using this code in DB2 :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_SAMPLE1()
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE V_DESCRIPTION_1 VARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE V_DESCRIPTION_2 VARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE sys cursor FOR select DESCRIPTION_1, DESCRIPTION_2 from DESC;
open sys;
TEST:
LOOP 
IF (sys IS NOT FOUND) THEN // **error in this line**
LEAVE TEST;
END IF;
fetch FROM sys INTO V_DESCRIPTION_1,V_DESCRIPTION_2;
-- other treatments
    END IF;
END LOOP TEST;
close sys;
END;
```

I got this error :

```
SQL0206N  "SYS" is not valid in the context where it is used.  LINE NUMBER=15.
SQLSTATE=42703
```

Comment: Read about _condition handlers_ in the DB2 manual; you'll need to declare one for the "NOT FOUND" condition. By the way, names starting with "SYS" are usually reserved in DB2, it's not a good idea to use them for variables or object.

Comment: You can provide an constructive answer, instead of just writing a comment telling many things and not solving the question. Remember that StackOverFlow is an answers site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the cursor by a Select statement and my problem is solved :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_SAMPLE1()
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE V_DESCRIPTION_1 VARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE V_DESCRIPTION_2 VARCHAR(4000);

FOR v_row AS select DESCRIPTION_1, DESCRIPTION_2 from DESC DO   
-- other treatments

END FOR;

END;
```